# Take elements from Json to input in Picker

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing, react-native, fetch

I'm new in react native. I'm trying to fecth a webservice and input some element from response to a Picker (I use native-base). My problem is I don't know how to take an element (here it's `LIBELLE`) what I need in my Json.

see the code :

```
getSurfaces(){
    fetch('yourWebservice')
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((responseText) => {
            parseString(responseText, function (err, result) {
                responseText = result;
            });
            console.log(JSON.stringify(responseText));
            this.setState({
                surfaces: responseText.Surfaces.surface
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
            console.log(this.state.surfaces);
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error fetching the feed: ', err)
        })
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.getSurfaces();
}
```

My constructor:

```
constructor (){
    super();
    this.state = {
        date: '',
        surface: '',
        surfaces: [],
        start: '',
        hours : [],
    };
    this.valueChangeSurface = this.valueChangeSurface.bind(this);
}
valueChangeSurface(value: String){
    this.setState({
        surface: value
    });
}
```

My renderSurfaces method:

```
renderSurface(){
    if(this.state.surfaces){
        return this.state.surfaces.map((surface) => {
           return <Picker.Item label={surface.LIBELLE} value={surface}/>
        })
    }
}
```

The render of Picker:

```
<ListItem>
    <Left>
        <Text>Surface</Text>
    </Left>
    <Body>
        <Picker
            note
            inlineLabel={true}
            mode={"dropdown"}
            style={{width: 175}}
            selectedValue={this.state.surface}
            onValueChange={this.valueChangeSurface}>
            {
                this.renderSurface()
            }
        </Picker>
    </Body>
    <Right/>
</ListItem>
```

The error returned by `this.setState`in `getSurfaces()`:

> Error fetching the feed:  [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.setState({
>                       surfaces: responseText.Surfaces.surface
>                   }).catch')]

I don't really know if I take the good way to do this, I would really appreciate your help

Comment: dont edit your question with the provided answers... also this is getting confusing because we dont know what was like your code in first place

Comment: Oops, I'm new in the stack overflow so I did not understand that for add code to my question I needed to answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution :

The problem it was simple and the most part of it come from a syntaxe erreur, I replace :

```
responseText.Surfaces.surface.LIBELLE
```

by this :

```
responseText.Surfaces.surface[i].LIBELLE
```

See the entire code of getSurfaces():

```
getSurfaces(){ // Input the surfaces values (ID and LIBELLE) who come from WebService in the this.state.surfaces
    fetch('url')
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((responseText) => {
            parseString(responseText, function (err, result) {
                responseText = result;
            });
            let sf = []; // Create a table who gonna content the value of this.state.surfaces
            for(i = 0; i<responseText.Surfaces.surface.length; i++){
                sf.push(responseText.Surfaces.surface[i].LIBELLE.toString());
            }
            this.setState({
                surfaces: sf //inject the table sf who contain the table surfaces
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error fetching the feed: ', err)
        })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify()` turns a JS object to a json string. And also, you dont need of interacting over the object to set the state.

```
this.setState({
     surfaces: responseText.Surfaces.surface;
});
```

You've already the surface has an JS Object.

In your code you are interacting over a JSON string object when you are rendering the component, and giving to the `result` the last JSON object,

`{"ID":["4"],"LIBELLE":["Quicks"],"CODE":["QUICKS"],"ORDRE":["4"]}`

into a JSON String object,

`'{"ID":["4"],"LIBELLE":["Quicks"],"CODE":["QUICKS"],"ORDRE":["4"]}'`

Before rendering the component, you can render surfaces e.g.

```
renderSurfaces() {
    if (this.state.surfaces) {
        return this.state.surfaces.map((surface) => {
            return (
                    <Text>
                        {surface.LIBELLE}
                    </Text>
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer It's almost what I need. I edited getSurface () with your changes and I already had renderSurfaces () but I replaced it by yours and now, the only problem that remains come from `this.state` who generate an error : `TypeError: this.setState is not a function. (In 'this.setState({surfaces: responseText.Surfaces.surface})', 'this.setState' is undefined)]`

Comment: @Bastien, can you pls edit your question with your component full code here pls?

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide an object for your Picker. Now you're converting your object to a string, use this instead:

```
surfaces.forEach(result => {
    this.setState({
        surfaces: result
    });
    console.log(this.state.surfaces);
}
```

The `surfaces.forEach(e => {})` is the same as your loop there just a little bit simpler. Keep in mind that you don't need to use can use this kind of loops (forEach, map) almost always in JS.
If this doesn't help, please post the html snippet of you Picker.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had trying what you have made but it seems doesn't works, `console.log(result)` generate an error : 

`Error fetching the feed:  [TypeError: _iterator[typeof Symbol === 'function' ? Symbol.iterator : '@@iterator'] is not a function. (In '_iterator[typeof Symbol === 'function' ? Symbol.iterator : '@@iterator']()', '_iterator[typeof Symbol === 'function' ?
Symbol.iterator : '@@iterator']' is undefined)]`

Comment: Ok. please post the render method to provide more information